# How to toggle a div when the page is load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery, I have a div visible on a page `#section-nav`, i'm currently re using some script, at the moment the code make disappear a series of li on hover on `#section-nav.`

I would need the opposite process so

- the div #li is not visible on load
- only at hover on #section-nav the li became visible
- I would like use toggle effect

I'm really new at jquery, could you post a sample of code? thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#section-nav").hover(function () {
        $("li").slideToggle("fast");
    }); }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div `#li` ? is it the id or the element type? if it's the type:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").hide();
    $("#section-nav").hover(function() {
        $("li").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});​
```

If it's the id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#li").hide();
    $("#section-nav").hover(function() {
        $("#li").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});​
```

You can use the $(function(){}) syntax to reduce code:

```
$(function(){
    $("li").hide();
    $("#section-nav").hover(function() {
        $("li").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: great now is working thanks! PS now when i move on li, the li disappear, any idea how to keep them visible?

Comment: @GibboK. It's for another Question, anyway it's hard to say without the markup. you need to give a fiddle.